# How do you include a custom npm package to Google Dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, package.json, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have been trying to add package "alphanum-increment" to my fulfillment of the Google Dialogflow. I've found couple of pointers to include it in package.json under dependencies but couldn't find the exact way to include it.

Thanks in advance for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to get this done by just indicating the functions that I would use from the package.

```
const {increment} = require("alphanum-increment");
```

And anywhere you like to use the function, you can include it directly

```
var orgStr = "N0001";
var updStr = increment(orgStr);//updStr = N0002
```

The same can be achieved by -

```
const alphanumOp = require(alphanum-increment);
//In your function
var updStr = alphanumOp.increment(orgStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple since you said you want to include it in your package.json. You have to include the name of the npm package.

```
 {
    "some": "crazyPropsFoo",
    "engines": {},
    "scripts": {},
    "dependencies": {
      "actions-on-google": "^1.5.x",
      "firebase-admin": "~4.1.2",
      "firebase-functions": "~0.5",
      "alphanum-increment": "0.0.2",   // Here you include yours
      }
    }
```

Then you just need to require the package in your 'index.js' file:

```
var PackageObj = require("alphanum-increment").PackageObject;
var yourVar = new PackageObj();
```

Comment: Getting an error **Detailed stack trace: TypeError: PackageObj is not a constructor**. Copy pasted from the above mentioned in respective files.

Comment: Because PackageObj probably is not a constructor inside the function, which makes it undefined. You should declare it first so it is included.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Kind of a rookie here. Should the PackageObj be included as a dependencies? or is it some kind of a direct inclusion

Comment: Hey, no the error specified here is more programming related. Here you can find some good documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor regarding this and you should try to look around for javascript doc to understand the basics.